# Young Adult book about a crack in the sidewalk

Tags: story-identification, underground-civilization

I read this book when I was very young, so it might have been published in the 60's or 70's. Definitely not 80's or later. I'm not sure whether it was a children's book or YA. I think it was about a boy who drops something, which falls through a crack in the sidewalk or the street. He somehow gets inside the crack in search of the object and follows a tunnel or a crevasse down to an underground grotto where there's a lake and a city around the lake, with weird inhabitants. I think the book was illustrated with cartoonish black and white line art.

Comment: Magical setting? Or "real world"?

Comment: This makes me think of [The Secret World of Og](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/869040.The_Secret_World_of_Og) except that was a group of kids going down through a trap door.